# web scraping saves all values from table twice

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have saved the following code and for some reason, the program saves all the values from the table twice in the array "stmat" which can be seen if you print it,can anyone say why and how to stop it from appending it twice

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
path="C:\\python\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"
import numpy
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
web = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/in/devanahalli/VOBL/date/2011-9"
driver.get(web)
time.sleep(15)
html = driver.page_source
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
stat_table = soup.find_all('table', class_ ='days ng-star-inserted')
stat_table = stat_table[0]
stmat = []
count = 0
for row in stat_table.find_all('tr') :
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        stmat.append(cell.text)
        count = count + 1
print(count)
print(stmat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is because of html structure like below:  `td` in `td`.

[image]

So you can modify code using find `table`:

print line by line to debug your code.

```
stat_table = soup.find_all('table', class_ ='days ng-star-inserted')
stmat = []
count = 0

for table in stat_table:
    for cell in table.find_all('table'):
        stmat.append(cell.text)
        print(cell.text)
        count = count + 1
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think the problem is in your indentation of for loops, there is no white spaces for second for loop " Both for loops are at same level " give white-spaces for second array.